# Select a specific Item from a list<generic> by one of its variable

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a `List<> Generic` .The generic class has variables inside such as `variable1`,`variable2`,`variable3`....

I want to create a new instance of a *generic* class with values coming from a specific item in this list where generic's `variable3 = some value`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GenericClass item = yourList.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.variable3 == "somevalues");
```

If you only need to select a single item which met the criteria, then you can use,

- [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) Returns the first item in the list, or throw an exception if none found
- [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) Returns the first item in the list or default value
- [Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) Returns the only item in the list, if more than a single item met the criteria or none met the criteria then an exception would be thrown
- [SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) Returns the only item in the list, if more than a single item met the criteria then an exception would be thrown, if none is found, default value is returned
- [Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) Returns the last item in the list, or throw an exception of none found
- [LastOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx) Returns the last item in the list or default value